# PHP evaluating the content of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to evaluate the content of an array. The array contain water temperatures submitted by a user.

The user submits 2 temperaures, one for hot water and one for cold water.

What I need is to evaluate both array items to find if they are within  the limits, the limits are "Hot water: between 50 and 66", "Cold water less than 21".

If either Hot or Cold fail the check flag the Status "1" or if they both pass the check flag Status "0".

Below is the code I am working with:

```
$row_WaterTemp['HotMin'] = "50";
$row_WaterTemp['Hotmax'] = "66";

$SeqWaterArray new(array);

$SeqWaterArray = array("58", "21");


foreach($SeqWaterArray as $key => $val) {
    $fields[] = "$field = '$val'";
    if($key == 0) { 
        if($val < $row_WaterTemp['HotMin'] || $val > $row_WaterTemp['Hotmax']) {
            $Status = 1;
            $WaterHot = $val;
        } else {
            $Status = 0;
            $WaterHot = $val;
        }

    }

    if($key == 1) {
        if($val > $row_WaterTemp['ColdMax']) {
            $Status = 1;
            $WaterCold = $val;
        } else {
            $Status = 0;
            $WaterCold = $val;
        }
    }   

}
```

My question is:

When I run the script the array key(0) works but when the array key(1) is evaluted the status flag for key(1) overrides the status flag for key0.
If anyone can help that would be great.
Many thanks for your time.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to ask the question. Now I have.

Comment: Add a `$row_WaterTemp['ColdMax'] = ...` to your question? What does this do? `$SeqWaterArray new(array);`? should it be: `$SeqWaterArray = array();`? May I suggest you turn on 'display errors' - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Answer (score 0):

It seems OK to me, exept for the values at limit, and you can simplify

```
$row_WaterTemp['HotMin'] = "50";
$row_WaterTemp['Hotmax'] = "66";

$SeqWaterArray = array("58", "21");
$Status = array() ;

foreach($SeqWaterArray as $key => $val) {
    if($key == 0) { 
        $Status = ($val >= $row_WaterTemp['HotMin'] && $val <= $row_WaterTemp['Hotmax']) ;
        $WaterHot = $val;
    } else if($key == 1) {
        $Status += ($val >= $row_WaterTemp['ColdMax']) ;
        $WaterCold = $val;
    }
}
```

If one fails, `$Status = 1`, if the two tests failed, `$Status = 2`, if it's ok, `$Status = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// this function return BOOL (true/false) when the condition is met
function isBetween($val, $min, $max) {
  return ($val >= $min && $val <= $max);
}

$coldMax = 20; $hotMin = 50; $hotMax = 66;

// I decided to simulate a test of more cases:
$SeqWaterArray['john'] = array(58, 30);
$SeqWaterArray['martin'] = array(34, 15);
$SeqWaterArray['barbara'] = array(52, 10);

foreach($SeqWaterArray as $key => $range) {
    $flag = array();
    foreach($range as $type => $temperature) {
        // here we fill number 1 if the temperature is in range 
        if ($type == 0) {
            $flag['hot'] = (isBetween($temperature, $hotMin, $hotMax) ? 0 : 1);     
        } else {
            $flag['cold'] = (isBetween($temperature, 0, $coldMax) ? 0 : 1);     
        }                
    }
    $results[$key]['flag'] = $flag;                
}

var_dump($results);

?>
```

**This is the result:**

```
["john"]=> 
     "flag"=> 
        ["hot"]=> 1
        ["cold"]=> 0 
["martin"]=> 
     "flag" => 
        ["hot"]=> 1 
        ["cold"]=> 0 
["barbara"]=> 
    "flag" => 
        ["hot"]=> 0 
        ["cold"]=> 0
```

Comment: ..and what happened to the check for cold water?

Comment: Yes you test both temperatures but only whether they are within the limits for hot water. If you look at OPs' code you will notice that there is a check for a cold water limit as well.

Comment: You better take a look at OPs' question or his code. Your function checks whether the temperature is between 55 and 66 for **both** values. But OP wants the second temperature to be checked against the cold water limit.

Comment: But you are still not checking the second value for `$row_WaterTemp['ColdMax'])` as OP does in his code.

Comment: @simon Finally got it... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use break statement in this case when the flag is set to 1. As per your specification the Cold water should be less than 21, I have modified the code.

```
<?php

$row_WaterTemp['HotMin'] = "50";
$row_WaterTemp['Hotmax'] = "66";
$row_WaterTemp['ColdMax'] = "21";

$SeqWaterArray = array("58", "21");


foreach($SeqWaterArray as $key => $val) {
    $fields[] = "$key = '$val'";
    if($key == 0) { 
        if($val < $row_WaterTemp['HotMin'] || $val > $row_WaterTemp['Hotmax']) {
            $Status = 1;
            $WaterHot = $val;
            break;
        } else {
            $Status = 0;
            $WaterHot = $val;
        }

    }
if($key == 1) {
    if($val >= $row_WaterTemp['ColdMax']) {
        $Status = 1;
        $WaterCold = $val;
        break;
    } else {
        $Status = 0;
        $WaterCold = $val;
    }
}   

}
echo $Status;
```

?>

This way it would be easier to break the loop in case if the temperature fails to fall within the range in either case.

https://eval.in/636912

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need a `foreach` loop here since you are working with a simple array and apparently you know that the first element is the hot water temperature and the second element is the cold water temperature. I would just do something like this:

```
$row_WaterTemp['HotMin'] = 50;
$row_WaterTemp['HotMax'] = 66;
$row_WaterTemp['ColdMax'] = 21;

$SeqWaterArray = array(58, 21);

$waterHot = $SeqWaterArray[0];
$waterCold = $SeqWaterArray[1];

$status = 0;

if ($waterHot < $row_WaterTemp['HotMin'] || $waterHot > $row_WaterTemp['HotMax']) {
    $status = 1;
}
if ($waterCold > $row_WaterTemp['ColdMax']) {
    $status = 1;
}
```

You can combine the `if` statements of course. I separated them because of readability.

Note that I removed all quotes from the numbers. Quotes are for strings, not for numbers.